Array can't expand even though cells are empty
First time poster here.
In my Google Sheets spreadsheet, there is an array formula that refuses to expand to fill the adjacent cells like it's supposed to.  I have tried both QUERY and FILTER but neither one expands.
Picture of afforementioned spreadsheet
All the cells next to it are empty.  I've tried filling them in and clearing them countless times to no avail.  I cannot delete the cells because it claims they are part of an array (even when I remove the array formula).  It's like there's remnant ghost data there or something.
Is there any way to fix this so my array can properly expand and fill the cells??
Here is my file. The problem is on the 'Compare Dogs' sheet.
Thank you so much for your help!

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Weirdly enough I tried deleting those cells with errors the filter and query formula works. I believe you only need to implement error catching functions like IFERROR()

To avoid conflicts in array formula result areas, use array_constrain() or another similar means to ensure results do not overlap.
Cell H20:
=array_constrain(ifna(filter(All!BL:BL, All!$A:$A = A20)), 1, 9^9)

Cell V20:
=array_constrain(ifna(filter(All!AH:AH, All!$A:$A = O20)), 1, 9^9)

Cell AB20:
=array_constrain(ifna(filter(All!BL:BL, All!$A:$A = O20)), 1, 9^9)

See array_constrain().

Oh, this worked wonderfully!  Thank you so much! :D


You should recheck all your formulas in the above tables (Females, Males) as you can see in the screenshot how a formula in Cell_H20 has its output overlapping into below table & is the root cause!


Oh, I see!  What would be the best way to rectify this??  Would using IF to only run the formula if the Name cell is full work?

Well that's one idea & it could work for most but not all; the other issue being query() & filter() pull more than one row(s) of data as output. For some scenarios you were using join() which is helping in restricting those multiple rows of output to single cell. But again join() is not used in some like Column H or Column V, which you need to check upon bcoz the formulas could be pulling multiple rows of data & they cant expand which will result in an error. On a side note if you just want to pull one match & not all matches; xlookup would do...

I will see if xlookup can do what I need! :D  Sorry everything is kind of a complicated mess haha
